# Open new page in current tab

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

I used Swing JxBrowser in my Java project.

When I click element on page, the new frame is showing where new page is loading.

I want to not create new frame but load page in current tab.

I used demo app source (version 6.12) from [JxBrowser page](http://cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/jxbrowser-6.12-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip).

I guess to use PopupHandler on Browser element.

Comment: Could you post a link to the code or add it to the question?

Comment: I edit and put link :)

Comment: I'm ok you solved your question, but don't post your code in a link, instead post it in your question in the [mcve] form. @Titulum please stop recommending for a link to the code, OP should have posted it on the question. OP, please post your code here.

Comment: This code is simple demo application from JxBrowser page and I paste link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

It was easier as I though.

```
browser.setPopupHandler(new PopupHandler() {
        @Override
        public PopupContainer handlePopup(PopupParams popupParams) {
            browser.loadURL(popupParams.getURL());

            return null;
        }
    });
```